# Javascript : Continue execution after ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- On load of the page, the code should do a $.getJSON request (which
  basically is an ajax get request) (on success yayy just continue execution otherwise go down this list).
- when this fails with code 400 I would like to wait 1 second and retry this request (if this succeeds than yayy continue code execution otherwise go down this list)
- after that just skip the ajax get request and continue executing the other code.

But Currently, I can't manage to continue to execute the code because of the thrown error. For this I tried :

```
try{
    $.getJSON('/services/getData').success(function(data) {
        configurationObject = data["configuration"];                            
    })
} catch(err) {
    console.log("error");
}
```

and

```
$.getJSON('/services/getData').success(function(data) {
    configurationObject = data["configuration"];                            
})
.error(function(){
    console.log("keep running please")
}
```

but both just stops the execution of the complete javascript code. Is there any way I can keep running after an error occurred when using ajax calls?

Comment: What is the error you receive in the console? Are you sure that this is the code that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting used to [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for doing asynchronous tasks. this is how i would have done it if i where using jQuery

```
function getData() {
  return $.getJSON('/services/getData').then(function(data){
    configurationObject = data["configuration"];
    return configurationObject
  }, function(err) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    if (err.status === 400) {
      ? setTimeout(function () {
        dfd.resolve(getData());
      }, 1000)
    } else {
      dfd.reject(err)
    }
    return dfd.promise();
  })
}

getData().then(successFn, errorFn)
```

but if i could get lose on using es7 and async/await and just vanilla javascript then this is how i would have done it instead

```
const sleep = delay => new Promise(rs => setTimeout(rs, delay))

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('/services/getData')

  if (res.status === 400) {
    await sleep(1000)
    return getData()
  } else if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Could not get data')
  }

  const json = await res.json()
  configurationObject = json['configuration']
  return configurationObject
}

getData().then(successFn, errorFn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

`.error` handler has been removed. You can use `.fail` instead, whose handler receives a `jqXhr` argument. From that, you can read `status` to check for 400 etc.